# Convert values in related table to comma-separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, relational-database

I have two SQL Server tables:

```
TableA                  TableB
+------+--------+       +-----+------------+
| aid  |  Name  |       | aid |   Activity |
+------+--------+       +-----+------------+ 
| 1    |   Jim  |       | 1   |   Skiing   |
| 2    |   Jon  |       | 1   |   Surfing  |
| 3    |   Stu  |       | 1   |   Riding   |
| 4    |   Sam  |       | 3   |   Biking   |
| 5    |   Kat  |       | 3   |   Flying   |
+------+--------+       +-----+------------+
```

I'm trying to the following result where the related activities are in a comma-separated list:

```
+------+--------+------------------------------+
| aid  |  Name  |   Activity                   |
+------+--------+------------------------------+
| 1    |   Jim  |  Skiing, Surfing, Riding     |
| 2    |   Jon  |  NULL                        |
| 3    |   Stu  |  Biking, Flying              |
| 4    |   Sam  |  NULL                        |
| 5    |   Kat  |  NULL                        |
+------+--------+------------------------------+
```

I tried:

```
SELECT  aid, Name, STRING_AGG([Activity], ',') AS Activity
FROM    TableA 
        INNER JOIN TableB
        ON TableA.aid = TableB.aid
GROUP BY aid, Name
```

Can someone help me with this SQL query? Thank you.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  Do you have table structures?  What have you tried?

Comment: I'm in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v18.8. I read about something called STRING_AGG but couldn't figure out how to apply it.

Comment: I also looked at XML PATH but couldn't find an example similar enough to what I'm doing.

Comment: What happened when you tried that code, why didn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `OUTER APPLY` to aggregate the string if you're using SQL Server 2017 or higher.

```
drop table if exists #TableA;
go
create table #TableA (
  aid            int not null,
  [Name]         varchar(10) not null);

insert #TableA(aid, [Name]) values 
(1, 'Jim'),
(2, 'Jon'),
(3, 'Stu'),
(4, 'Sam'),
(5, 'Kat');

drop table if exists #TableB;
go
create table #TableB (
  aid            int not null,
  [Activity]     varchar(10) not null);

insert #TableB(aid, [Activity]) values 
(1, 'Skiing'),
(1, 'Surfing'),
(1, 'Riding'),
(3, 'Biking'),
(3, 'Flying');

select a.aid, a.[Name], oa.sa
from #TableA a
     outer apply (select string_agg(b.Activity, ', ') sa
                  from #TableB b
                  where a.aid=b.aid) oa;
```

```
Name    sa
Jim     Skiing, Surfing, Riding
Jon     NULL
Stu     Biking, Flying
Sam     NULL
Kat     NULL
```